# Dart 1.12.0 Intellij upgrade issues

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I have updated the dart-sdk and dartium but when I go into intellij to update the plug-in, It will tell me there is not a newer version from 141.1586 when 142.4509 is the latest version. So I have tried to download and install the plugin manually but I get an error "Plugin 'Dart' is incompatible with this installation". I have even gone as far as shutting down Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 and overwritting the files in the plugin directory (which didn't work). Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this issue?

I am running Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Have you considered creating a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com ?

Comment: I was hoping that it was a simple fix, but I can do that

Comment: I use WebStorm and didn't have any issues with updates, I also haven't seen it mentioned anywhere. I guess in this case a bug report is the best way to get people with deep knowledge have a look and possibly fix some things to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: I added the bug here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DEXP-62855#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest [Dart plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351) releases that have version 142.* are compatible only with [IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAPs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP).

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue